# Replace missing data from another data frame's column using for or rows_patch

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, dplyr

I have two data frames:

1. Main df with all the data, but some rows have NA - **mdata**
2. Rows that should be in first df instead of NA - **ldata**

[1 & 2 dataframes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcqhT.jpg)

I've tried to do a loop with the following logic: when I encounter NA I take the first row and replace NA with it, deleting the first row in the second df (so I don't need to count which one is going where):

```
  if(is.na(mdata$group_correct[i])){
    mdata[i,3] <- ldata [1,3]
    ldata <- ldata[-1,]
  }
}
```

There is a problem:

> the condition has length > 1

And there is a second way:

```
dplyr::rows_patch(
  x = mdata, 
  y = ldata, 
  by = "group_correct", 
  unmatched = "ignore"
)
```

Thing is, there are duplicates and the function doesn't work. So I was thinking, maybe I should put index before each row, using counter, for and gsub (i++ before the text), so the function won't give me an error and then deleting the index.

What is the most optimized way to solve the problem?